# Why tf.argmax() is returning wrong indexes?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to get the maximum indexes of logits using `tf.argmax()` function. My code is show below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

   
logits = tf.random_uniform([1,3,3,21], maxval=255, dtype=tf.float32, seed=0)
logits = logits / tf.norm(logits)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())

    logits_eval = sess.run(logits)
    logits_argmax_np = np.argmax(logits_eval, axis=-1)

    ypredT = tf.argmax(logits, axis=-1)
    logits_argmax_tf = ypredT.eval()
```

I can get the right indexes using `np.argmax()`, but I don't why`tf.argmax()` is returning wrong indexes.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Edit: I am using tensorflow 1.13

Comment: Would be helpful to have the version of tensorflow you are using, in order to recreate this. Things have changed fairly drastically between versions, and your use of tf.Session indicates this is not the latest version.

Comment: @FinleyGibson I am using tensorflow 1.13

Comment: `logits` will be different random tensor each time it is evaluated, so the two argmaxes will of course also be different.

Comment: @xdurch0 I thought that generating 'logits' variable by passing 'seed=0' to 'tf.random_uniform()'  would generate the same logits for each sess.run().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that each time you call `sess.run` you are instigating a separate execution of the session, from the bottom up. Since there are random numbers generated this will not produce the same result in each run, hence your argmax for each run is different. But they are doing the same thing.

To see this you can get both argmaxs from the same session execution, using square brackets to get both the `ypredT` tensor and the `logits` tensors from the same sess.run:

```
# tensorflow graph
logits = tf.random_uniform([1,3,3,21], maxval=255, dtype=tf.float32, seed=0) 
logits = logits / tf.norm(logits)
ypredT = tf.argmax(logits, axis=-1) # tensorflow argmax

# run session 
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    logits_eval, logits_argmax_tf = sess.run([logits, ypredT])

# after session has closed
logits_argmax_np = np.argmax(logits_eval, axis=-1) # get numpy argmax

print(logits_argmax_np)
print(logits_argmax_tf)
```

output:

```
[[[14  0  4]
  [ 0  8  0]
  [10 12  3]]]
[[[14  0  4]
  [ 0  8  0]
  [10 12  3]]]
```

Comment: Realized that "seed=0" is going to generate the same variable for each first run. It creates different variables in the second, third run so on and so forth… Thanks for the answer.